# Getting text from last marker to EOF in POSIX.2

Tags: text-processing

I have a text with marker lines like:

```
aaa
---
bbb
---
ccc
```

I need to get a text from the last marker (not inclusive) to EOF. In this case it will be

```
ccc
```

Is there an elegant way within POSIX.2? Right now I use two runs: first with `nl` and `grep` for the last occurrence with respective line number. Then I extract the line number and use `sed` to extract the chunk in question.

The text segments may be quite large, so I'm afraid to use some text-adding method like we add the text to a buffer, if we encounter the marker we empty the buffer, so that at EOF we have our last chunk in the buffer.

Answer (score 6):

Unless your segments are really huge (as in: you really can't spare that much RAM, presumably because this is a tiny embedded system controlling a large filesystem), a single pass is really the better approach. Not just because it'll be faster, but most importantly because it allows the source to be a stream, from which any data read and not saved is lost. This is really a job for awk, though sed can do it too.

```
sed -n -e 's/^---$//' -e 't a' \
       -e 'H' -e '$g' -e '$s/^\n//' -e '$p' -e 'b' \
       -e ':a' -e 'h'              # you are not expected to understand this
awk '{if (/^---$/) {chunk=""}      # separator ==> start new chunk
      else {chunk=chunk $0 RS}}    # append line to chunk
     END {printf "%s", chunk}'     # print last chunk (without adding a newline)
```

If you must use a two-pass approach, determine the line offset of the last separator and print from that. Or determine the byte offset and print from that.

```
</input/file tail -n +$((1 + $(</input/file         # print the last N lines, where N=…
                               grep -n -e '---' |   # list separator line numbers
                               tail -n 1 |          # take the last one
                               cut -d ':' -f 1) ))  # retain only line number
</input/file tail -n +$(</input/file awk '/^---$/ {n=NR+1} END {print n}')
</input/file tail -c +$(</input/file LC_CTYPE=C awk '
    {pos+=length($0 RS)}        # pos contains the current byte offset in the file
    /^---$/ {last=pos}          # last contains the byte offset after the last separator
    END {print last+1}          # print characters from last (+1 because tail counts from 1)
')
```

Addendum: If you have more than POSIX, here's a simple one-pass version that relies on a common extension to awk that allows the record separator `RS` to be a regular expression (POSIX only allows a single character). It's not completely correct: if the file ends with a record separator, it prints the chunk before the last record separator instead of an empty record. The second version using `RT` avoids that defect, but `RT` is specific to GNU awk.

```
awk -vRS='(^|\n)---+($|\n)' 'END{printf $0}'
gawk -vRS='(^|\n)---+($|\n)' 'END{if (RT == "") printf $0}'
```

Comment: @Gilles: `sed` is working fine, but I can't get the `awk` example to run; it hangs... and I get an error in 3rd example:  `cut -f ':' -t 1`  *... cut: invalid option -- 't'*

Comment: @fred.bear: I have no idea how that happened — I tested all my snippets, but somehow messed up the post-copy-paste edit on the `cut` example. I see nothing wrong with the `awk` example, what version of awk are you using, and what is your test input?

Comment: ... actually the `awk` version is working.. it is jut taking a *very* long time on a large file..  the `sed` version processed the same file in 0.470s ..  My test data is very weighted... only two chunks with a lone '---' three lines from the end of 1 million lines...

Comment: @Gilles.. (I think I  should stop testing at 3AM. I somehow tested all three of the "two pass" awks as a single unit :( ... I've now tested each individually and the second one is **very fast** at *0.204 seconds* ... Howerver, the first "two-pass" awk  outputs only: "**(standard input)**" (the -l seems to be the culprit) ... as for the third "two-pass" awk, I doesn't output anything... but the second "two-pass" is the fastest of all presented methods (POSIX or otherwise :)...

Comment: @fred.bear: Fixed, and fixed. My QA is not very good for these short snippets — I typically copy-paste from a command line, format, then notice a bug, and try to fix inline rather than reformat. I'm curious to see if counting characters is more efficient than counting lines (2nd vs 3rd two-pass methods).

Comment: @Gilles.. The first "two-pass" takes *0.048 seconds*... and, for the unknowing (like me:) it seems that `</input/file` must be on the same logical line as `grep` (btw:  What is the `<file` process actually called?) ... The third "two-pass" takes *0.774 seconds*.  ... The `gawk` "RT" method takes *0.221s*

Answer (score 4):

```
lnum=$(($(sed -n '/^---$/=' file | sed '$!d') +1)); sed -n "${lnum},$ p" file
```

The first `sed` ouputs line numbers of the "---" lines...
The second `sed` extracts the last number from the first sed's output...
Add 1 to that number to get the start of your "ccc" block...
The third 'sed' outputs from the start of the "ccc" block to EOF

**Update** *(with ammended info re Gilles methods)*

Well I was wondereing about how *glenn jackman's* `tac` would perform, so I time-tested the three answers (at the time of writing)...  The test file(s) each contained 1 million lines (of their own line numbers).
All answers did what was expected...

Here are the times..

---

*Gilles* `sed` (single pass)

```
# real    0m0.470s
# user    0m0.448s
# sys     0m0.020s
```

---

*Gilles* `awk` (single pass)

```
# very slow, but my data had a very large data block which awk needed to cache.
```

---

*Gilles* 'two-pass' (first method)

```
# real    0m0.048s
# user    0m0.052s
# sys     0m0.008s
```

---

*Gilles* 'two-pass' (second method) ... **very fast**

```
# real    0m0.204s
# user    0m0.196s
# sys     0m0.008s
```

---

*Gilles* 'two-pass' (third method)

```
# real    0m0.774s
# user    0m0.688s
# sys     0m0.012s
```

---

*Gilles* 'gawk' (RT method) ... **very fast**, but is not POSIX.

```
# real    0m0.221s
# user    0m0.200s
# sys     0m0.020s
```

---

*glenn jackman* ... **very fast**, but is not POSIX.

```
# real    0m0.022s
# user    0m0.000s
# sys     0m0.036s
```

---

*fred.bear*

```
# real    0m0.464s
# user    0m0.432s
# sys     0m0.052s
```

---

*Mackie Messer*

```
# real    0m0.856s
# user    0m0.832s
# sys     0m0.028s
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, which of my two-pass versions did you test, and what version of awk did you use?

Comment: @Gilles: I used GNU Awk 3.1.6 (in Ubuntu 10.04 with 4 GB RAM). All tests have 1 million lines in the first "chunk",then a "marker" followed by 2 "data" lines...It took 15.540 seconds to process a smaller file of 100,000 lines, but for the 1,000,000 lines, I'm running it now, and it has been more than 25 minutes so far. It is using one core to 100% ... killing it now... Here are some more incremental tests: lines=100000 (0m16.026s) -- lines=200000 (2m29.990s) -- lines=300000 (5m23.393s) -- lines=400000 (11m9.938s)

Comment: Oops.. In my above comment, I missed your "two-pass" awk reference. The above detail is for the "single-pass" awk... The awk version is correct... I've made further comment re the different "two-pass" versions under your answer (an modified the time results above)

Answer (score 3):

A two pass strategy seems to be the right thing. Instead of sed I would use `awk(1)`. The two passes could look like this:

```
$ LINE=`awk '/^---$/{n=NR}END{print n}' file`
```

to get the line number. And then echo all text starting from that line number with:

```
$ awk "NR>$LINE" file
```

This should not require excessive buffering.

Comment: and then they can be combined: `awk -v line=$(awk '/^---$/{n=NR}END{print n}' file) 'NR>line' file`

Comment: Seeing that I've been time testing the other submissions, I've now also tested "glen jackman's" above snippet. It takes *0.352 seconds* (with the same data file mentioned in my answer)... I'm starting to get the message that awk can be faster than I originally thought possible (I thought sed was about as good as it got, but it seems to be a case of "horses for courses")...

Comment: Very interesting to see all these scripts benchmarked. Nice work Fred.

Comment: The fastest solutions use **tac** and **tail** which actually read the input file backwards. Now, if only awk could read the input file backwards...

Answer (score 3):

Use "[tac](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tac)" which outputs a file's lines from end to beginning:

```
tac afile | awk '/---/ {exit} {print}' | tac
```

Comment: `tac` isn't POSIX, it's Linux-specific (it's in GNU coreutils, and in some busybox installations).

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `ed`

```
ed -s infile <<\IN
.t.
1,?===?d
$d
,p
q
IN
```

How it works: `t` duplicates the current (`.`) line - which is always the last line when `ed` starts (just in case the delimiter is present on the last line), `1,?===?d` deletes all lines up to and including the previous match (`ed` is still on the last line) then `$d` deletes the (duplicate) last line, `,p` prints the text buffer (replace with `w` to edit the file in place) and finally `q` quits `ed`.

---

If you know there's at least one delimiter in the input (and don't care if it's also printed) then

```
sed 'H;/===/h;$!d;x' infile
```

would be the shorter.
How it works: it appends all lines to the `H`old buffer, it overwrites the `h`old buffer when encountering a match, it `d`eletes all lines except the la`$`t one when it e`x`changes buffers (and autoprints).